# elasticsearch failed to get events

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have two events in elasticsearch:

Event 1:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2013.11.26",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "apuoW1Y8SBqVk_W_FOPKQQ",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2013-11-26T03:09:16.059Z",
    "message": "testline3\ntestline1\n testline2\n testline3",
    "@version": "1",
    "type": "online_log",
    "host": [
      "suutw11"
    ],
    "path": [
      "/home/infra/logstash/test/test1.log",
      "%{@source_path}"
    ],
    "env": "SAT1",
    "tags": [
      "multiline",
      "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
  }
}
```

Event 2:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2013.11.26",
  "_type": "logs",
  "_id": "mMk-JBWjQh2Xmc8ERIDzmw",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "@source": "file://sudpb1/app/bckss04/dmacms_ear_p4_A/acmsdomain/logs/access.log",
    "@source_host": "sudpb1",
    "@message": "10.100.2.66\t2013-11-26\t15:22:18\tGET\t/lb_check.jsp\t200\t3\t0.0010",
    "@tags": [
      "beaver"
    ],
    "@fields": {
      "host": [
        "sudpb1"
      ],
      "env": [
        "BCV"
      ]
    },
    "@timestamp": "2013-11-26T04:24:29.471Z",
    "@source_path": "/app/bckss04/dmacms_ear_p4_A/acmsdomain/logs/access.log",
    "@type": "access_log",
    "@version": "1",
    "type": "redis-input"
  }
}
```

Both events can be get by:

```
curl -XGET 'http://sulog01:9200/logstash-2013.11.26/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

But Event 1 can not be get by:

```
curl -XGET 'http://sulog01:9200/logstash-2013.11.26/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*"
    }
  }
}'
```

The later syntax is used by kibana so I would like to know what caused this different behavior and how to fix this so that the later syntax can also get all the events.

Comment: you are searching on the _all field throuhg your last query. did you maybe disable it at some point in the mapping? Probably better to specify the fields you want to search on?

Comment: Thank very much that is a very good hint! I actually did disabled the _all field to save disk spaces. It looks like re-enabled _all field solved my problem

Comment: Glad to hear, added my comment as an answer then.

Comment: Could you please accept/upvote my answer if it was useful?

Answer (score 0):

You are searching on the `_all` field using your last query, as you don't specify a field a field name in the query, nor a default field. I think you might have disabled the `_all` field at some point in the mapping, which would cause the documents that don't have the `_all` field not to be returned.